# Pytroch model deployment on GCP got 400 error in valid Json format for output

Tags: google-cloud-platform

```
def preprocess(self, data):
    """ Preprocessing input request by tokenizing
        Extend with your own preprocessing steps as needed
    """

    logger.info(f"{data}")

    # The structure of End point request[{'body': {'instances': [{'data': {'value': 'Write python function to iterate through list'}}]}}]

    inputs = self.tokenizer(data[0]['body']['instances'][0]['data']['value'], return_tensors="pt").input_ids

    return inputs

def inference(self, inputs):
    """ Predict the class of a text using a trained transformer model.
    """
    inputs = inputs.to(self.device)
    prediction = self.model.generate(input_ids=inputs, max_length=4000, do_sample=True,pad_token_id=self.tokenizer.eos_token_id)
    

    logger.info("Model predicted: '%s'", prediction)
    print("prediction shape:", prediction.shape)
    print("prediction content:", prediction)
    
    return prediction

def postprocess(self, inference_output):
    inference_output = self.tokenizer.batch_decode(inference_output, skip_special_tokens=True)
    logger.info(f"{inference_output}")
    print(type(inference_output))
    return inference_output




def handle(self, data, context):
    
    """
    Invoke by TorchServe for prediction request.
    Do pre-processing of data, prediction using model and postprocessing of prediciton output
    :param data: Input data for prediction
    :param context: Initial context contains model server system properties.
    :return: prediction output
    """
  
    if not self.initialized:
        self.initialized(context)

       
      
    model_input = self.preprocess(data)
    model_output = self.inference(model_input)
    final_output = self.postprocess(model_output)
    # Perform post-processing on model_output to get prediction result
    prediction_result = [final_output[0]]

    # Convert the prediction result to a JSON object
    json_result = json.dumps(prediction_result, ensure_ascii=False)
    # convert JSON string to Python dictionary
    json_obj = json.loads(json_result)
    #print the JSON object
    print(type(json_obj))
    #Return the JSON object
    
    return json_obj
```

I deploy the model on gcp I got this error when I sent request {
"error": {
"code": 400,
"message": "The output data is not valid json.",
"status": "FAILED_PRECONDITION"
}
}
I can the see the prediction output in the logs, Can anyone help with this error please

I tried to make sure that the output is valid Json object